# I opened my app in Xcode 10 and now I have errors in 9.4.1 : SDKApplicationDelegate (FacebookCore)

Tags: swift, facebook

I opened my app with the beta version of Xcode 10 to check if it was compatible with iOS 12, and now if I try to build my project in the stable version of Xcode I have 2 errors in the SDKApplicationDelegate (FacebookCore) :

```
@discardableResult
  public func
    application(_ application: UIApplication,
                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    return delegate?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) ?? false
  }
```

--> ''LaunchOptionsKey' is not a member type of 'UIApplication''

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
  @discardableResult
  public func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                          open url: URL,
                          options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return delegate?.application(app,
                                 open: url,
                                 sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                 annotation: options[.annotation]) ?? false
  }
```

--> 'OpenURLOptionsKey' is not a member type of 'UIApplication'

I tried to update my pods but nothing changed.

Do I have to manually change these lines of code ?

Answer (score 6):

Change them to `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey`. Just remove the `.` (dot) in between them. It will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After making compatible with Xcode 9, Xcode 10 is throwing an error. is there any way to make a code change which works for both 9 & 10?

Comment: Just add the dot again when working with Xcode 10. There is no other way. Kindly upvote if it worked

Comment: It's work to me. I create and open only on Xcode 9.4.1.

Answer (score 6):

This is xcode version problem. I got same error. While integrating Facebook kit my friend had created project in Xcode10. But i'm using Xcode 9.
Simply just replaced,
**UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey** to **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey** 
 and
**UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey** to **UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey**.
 After clean my project, it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I think you have to manually change the lines of code. I personally stuck to the Xcode beta because my device runs ios 12.

Some advice which I took into action after this makes a backup zip file of your project before you switch Xcode versions.

Comment: Did you manage to find the updated versions of theses lines of code ?

Comment: Na. I did fix them but shortly after that as I realized I couldn't test it on my device I reverted back to Xcode 10. Sorry